# Process ending with using crontab

Tags: c++, process, segmentation-fault, cron

For our group's code, I run our unit tests overnight on my work PC using crontab. For each unit test, the script checks out a fresh version of the code from the repository, compiles it, runs the tests, and send emails to everyone in the group, depending on what happens.

Lately, when the tests get testing our wrapper around Snopt, I get the following messages:

```
[myPC:32591] *** Process received signal ***
[myPC:32591] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[myPC:32591] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[myPC:32591] Failing at address: 0x20e6000
```

I've replaced the name of my PC with "myPC". I'm not sure what this means tho. From the searches I've done, these errors typically occur with mpi, but the code being used is serial.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated; I can't be the only one with this issue, so I hope this can be a resource for others that might run into this problem.

Comment: Well, that probably means that one of the new unit tests caused a segmentation fault.  Check which new tests were added, or what was changed in the codebase, that could cause such error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to initialize the pointer member variables of the new class. Thanks for the input!